# To find element from the drop down list

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to go to http://www.partners.org/ -->FOR PATIENTS--> Find a physician, the second value  from this drop down
But it is not able to find the element. 
Below is the HTMl:

```
<div id="nav-item-1" class="nav-dropdown" style="display: none;">
<div class="nav_tab"> </div>
<div class="drpdwn">
<ul>

<li>
<li>
     <a target="_self" href="/Doctors/PhysicianFinder.aspx">Find a Physician</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
```

Below is my code.

Can some one help me with this please?

```
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.partners.org/");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn_nav-item-1")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='drpdwn']/li[2]")).Click();
```

Comment: From the context, it looks like this is Webdriver on C#? If so, please add the C# tag; if not, please add whatever the appropriate language tag is to your post.

Comment: That said, the issue may just be with your HTML. You don't close your first `<li>` tag, so XPath may not be finding the second one. Use `<li />` or `<li></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='/Doctors/PhysicianFinder.aspx']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
driver.findelement(By.linktext("Find a Physician")).click()
```